# Update item with REST

Tags: javascript, rest, anonymous-authentication

I am trying to update an item in SharePoint list. I am logged in as anonymous user. It's a farm solution visual webpart, and I have this code:

```
  values["__metadata"] = { "type": "SP.Data.ServicesListItem" };
        var itemData = JSON.stringify(values);
        var headers = {
            'X-HTTP-Method':'PATCH',
            'If-Match': '*',
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        };
        var dfd = $.ajax({
            url: encodeURI(updateUrl),
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
            data: itemData,
            headers: headers
        });
```

It's working for the administrator, but for anonymous, no.

I have this added in my ascx file but it's not working:

```
   <SharePoint:FormDigest ID="FormDigest1" runat="server"></SharePoint:FormDigest>
```

Any idea?

Comment: Have you given the permission for `Require Use Remote Interfaces permission` ? Which steps you have done for anonymous access?

Answer (score 3):

Try below steps to enable CSOM for Anonymous users:

**First give permissions at Web application level**

**Steps:**

1. Go to Central Administration
2. Go to Manage Web Application
3. Select your Web App
4. Click on Authentication Providers in the ribbon
5. Click zone "Default".
6. Uncheck "Require Use Remote Interfaces Permission"

**Give permissions on site**

**Steps:**

- Go to **Site Settings** --> **Site Permissions**.
- Click the Anonymous Access button in the ribbon.
- Uncheck the check-box for **Require Use Remote Interfaces permission**.
- Click **OK**.

**Give permissions on the list**

**Steps:**

- Go to List Settings --> Permissions for this list.
- Stop Inheriting Permissions --> click OK
- For Anonymous access, give **Add** or **Edit** permissions.

**Reference:**

- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaevans/2013/10/24/what-every-developer-needs-to-know-about-sharepoint-apps-csom-and-anonymous-publishing-sites/
- https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sharepointdevelopersupport/2013/06/13/how-to-allow-anonymous-users-to-add-items-to-sharepoint-list-using-client-object-model/

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I have anonymous access enabled for the entire site. The require use remote interfaces permissions in "unchekced". What else could be the problem?

Comment: The list shows that it's inheriting permissions from the parent, but the permission levels are set to "View Items" Shouldn't it allow update as well?

Comment: Please also check these settings in central admin for that web application also.

Comment: The settings in the site collection override the settings in central administration ...

Comment: Shouldn't my list permissions for anonymous be: Allow Create, Update? It shows only "View Items"

Comment: Should I break the permissions on the list?

Comment: No. permission break on the list is not required. Try to change settings in the central admin for that web application. We need to give permission to anonymous user for using Client Side Object Model.

Comment: As I said earlier, the options are unchecked in my environment ..

Comment: Which error it throws?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49767/discussion-between-dikesh-gandhi-and-jacky).